# Is there a way to avoid redirecting the user to Laravel backend login page with Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, authentication, single-page-application, laravel-passport

I have a SPA on a different domain than **Laravel**. When a user logs in, he is redirected to **Laravel** and then redirected back to the SPA. Is it possible to avoid the behaviour and make the login process more user-friendly ?

Comment: How's the login on the SPA setup?

Comment: I'm trying different solutions with [Nuxt Auth](https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/) module, which is pre-configured for Passport, Sanctum, JWT, Google, Facebook...